# SqlCommand not executing

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I don't understand why my code doesn't execute the `SqlCommand` properly, even when I don't get any errors.

Here is my code:

```
_connection.Connection.OpenAsync();
_connection.SqlCommand.Connection = _connection.Connection;
_connection.SqlCommand.CommandText = "insert into test (id, name) values ('dq1we3','d2qwe3')";
_connection.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
_connection.Dispose();
```

And here I initialize `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`:

```
private readonly string _conString = Settings.Default.RssConnectionString;

public SqlConnection Connection;
public SqlCommand SqlCommand;

public TestConnection()
{
    Connection = new SqlConnection(_conString);
    SqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are u sure that you are checking the correct database, because I usually make mistake by checking the wrong Database table for not being inserted though no errors.

Comment: Does this `_connection.Connection.OpenAsync(); ` need to be awaited, before it can be used to execute a command?

Comment: you seem to be using difference variables in your first bit of code to the second - how are these bits of code related?  what happens when you step through the code?

Comment: @ArulManivannan, yep, I've rechecked :)

Comment: You did not show how you executing your code. Is it inside a method and you calling that method?

Comment: @MaxSorin i think not, okay made correct there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be doing something like this:

```
using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) // using automatically disposes of object
{
    myConnection.Open();

    string commandText = "insert into test (id, name) values ('dq1we3','d2qwe3')";

    using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, myConnection))
    {
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, it's working, thanks, but, why my variant is not working properly? what i've been missed there?

Comment: I imagine it's since you're using `OpenAsync` and the following code gets executed before that operation is completed since you're not `await`ing it.

Comment: yep, you right. I've removed async and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set connection string first before opening connection?

```
_connection.SqlCommand.Connection = _connection.Connection;
_connection.Connection.OpenAsync();
```

Comment: Had tried your variant, it not work. Connection is opened but it didn't execute my sql command to insert some data.

Comment: The problem is that you're not awaiting the `OpenAsync()` method.